# Using Expo camera recording video upload server using axios api request showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Using Expo camera recording video upload server using Axios API request showing error give me any solution to upload video
I have followed this link to `upload video`
http://5.9.10.113/67057902/uploading-video-recorded-with-expo-camera-to-server

Here is my **code** :

```
const videoMergeAction = async () => {
  
try {

// commit("LOADING",true);
setisLoading(true)

let data = new FormData();

data.append("first_video_file",{
  name:"firstVideo.mp4",
  uri:firstVideo,
  type:videoType1,
});
data.append("second_video_file", {
  
  name:"secondVideo.mp4",
  uri:secondVideo,
  type:videoType2,
});
data.append("third_video_file", {
  
  name:"thirdVideo.mp4",
  uri:thirdVideo,
  type:videoType3,
});


let config = {
    header: {
      "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`,
    },
   
  }


console.log('77',data);
const response  = await Api.post("/upload-video", data, config)
console.log('65',response.data);
if(response.status == 200) {
    console.log('87',response.data);
    setresVideoData(response.data.video_url)
    setVideoPath(response.data.video_path)
    // commit("LOADING",false);
    setisLoading(false)
    navigation.push('VideoPreview')
}


} catch (error) {
    console.log('video submit fail',error)
    setisLoading(false)
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. :(

Comment: I  am facing  Same  issue  here. Video submit fail [Network Error].